# How to set up Mail so To: auto completes based on Contacts info?

Tags: mail.app, email, contacts

When I type "mom" into the "To:" field, Mail.app doesn't load my mom's email addy:

[image]

...but when I click the blue "circle/plus" button and type "mom" it does:

[image]

In Contacts.app I have my Mom's contact info set up so that her "title" is "Mom".

How do I get Mail.app's To: field to auto complete based on her Contacts.app title? Or, is there something I can do in Mail.app so that "mom" will autocomplete her email addy from the To: field?

macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Title* is intended to be used within the scope of a company. If you want **Mail** to recognize names such as “Mom,” try using the *Nickname* field instead:

[image: Add Nickname]

On the macOS version of **Contacts**, you can go into **Contacts** → **Preferences** → **Template** → **Add Field** and *check* **Nickname**. That field will then become available by default when editing any contact, without requiring you to add it through the **+** menu.